# How to transition to a new iOS storyboard scene instance

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, segue, xcode-storyboard

I am developing a game for the iPad using Swift. The game is such that it is played in multiple rounds. Once a round has completed the scene for that round will transition to an end round scene that displays information about the completed round and prepares the player for the next round.

The storyboard for the game contains the round scene and segue from it to the end round scene. Because each round is essentially the same, it seems to make since to segue from the end round scene to another round scene.

Someone could use segue unwinding to move from the end round scene back to the completed round. It would be much better, however, since the current round is over, to segue to a completely new round scene and eliminate the completed round and end round scenes as they are no longer needed.

What is the best way to deal with scene transitions for this situation?

I’ve come up with something that appears to work. As far as I can see the only way I get rid of the results scene is to unwind, and so I’m having the action for the completed round that gets invoked during the unwind get rid of that completed round scene and create a new one using code like this:

```
@IBAction func handleUnwinding(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        let nextController: UIViewController! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TickingScene") as UIViewController

        var activeController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        if let navigationController = activeController as? UINavigationController {
            activeController = navigationController.visibleViewController!
        }
        else if let presentingViewController = activeController.presentingViewController {
            activeController = presentingViewController;
        }
        activeController.presentViewController(nextController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

I’m wondering how good this approach is, and whether there is a better alternative.

I came up with a different approach that seems to work better.

One thing I neglected to mention earlier is that I also had a start screen where the user could click a start button to begin the game. With the earlier implementation where it handled the unwinding, the start screen would appear briefly between transitions from the game scene and the results scene. This new method prevents that from happening.

This solution seems a bit heavy handed, only it seems to work better than anything else I’ve come up with.

What I did was I totally abandoned segues as they were not working for me, and instead I created a UINavigationController, making it the initial view controller in the storyboard. I configured it to hide the navigation bar, and when transition needed to happen between two scenes, the new scene would be created by calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier on the storyboard. Then the setControllers:animated method of the UINavigationController would be called giving it an array that only had the new scene. This got rid of the existing scene and transitioned to the new scene in one operation.

Comment: Personally, I would use the unwind segue back to the original view controller. The game state (including the "round") is a separate object - the "model" in MVC. The view controller is just concerned with conveying the information from the model to the view (and updating the model with the results of user interaction). When you unwind back you would allocate a new round and associate it with the existing view controller

Comment: The game state is a separate from the view controller. However, I believe that I may be able to embed the state for the game into the storyboard scene along with the view controller and let the Storyboard deal with initializing everything. If this is the case getting the program to segue to a new scene could potentially handle everything.

Comment: Integrating the game state into the view controller wouldn't be a best-practice design.  All you need to do with your current design is reset the game state in the unwind segue method of the game view controller

Comment: In general, designing things that can be reset makes them more complicated. It is often simpler to create something new and immutable when it is needed. I'm not planning on integrating the state directly into the view controller. I creating other objects that exist in the scene along side the controller. Some of them aren't even directly user interface related. The storyboard will create all of these objects when transitioning to the new scene. This is something I'm experimenting with, and it seems to be working out well so far.